# MVC. If the View does not know about the request how does it fetch data?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

In a MVC application it is easy to understand how the Controller extracts data from the request and updates the Model layer but I am a bit confused as to how a View is supposed to retrieve data from the Model layer when the View does not know about the request?

For example if I go to

```
http://www.site.com/product/view/428
```

I route the URL and I dispatch the request and I end up in the Controller. Nothing needs to be done in the Controller(I think?) and when it gets to my View I need the product ID but the View should not be extracting data from the Request so what do I do?

Thanks.

Comment: The controller takes whatever it needs from the request and passes it to the model to generate some model entity. Your view can then see that model entity.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I thought that the controller updates entities in the model layer, like updating a users account, it extracts the request data and updates the the model layer but the view requests data from the model layer I thought?

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis I believe you are wrong. View doesn't work with the Model. Controller is the link between them in MVC. So anything that is needed in the view should be passed by the controller.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis *[citation needed]* ..

Comment: @AliBZ I meant it as the Controller updates the model and makes it available to the view. This is what happens in MVC frameworks in web. But MVC doesn't force you to do that. The View can have a direct dependency on the Model, but not in the sense that it goes to it directly.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis so lets say for the URL above in my question, in the Product controller getView($productId) method it would use one of my services to load that product and save the object in my service in some class property and then retrieve the object in my view?

Comment: @David I don't know for PHP, but typically the controller will retrieve the entity from the model (through some service) and add it to some context which your View will have access to.

Comment: @tereško _A controller... It can also send commands to the model to update the model's state (e.g., editing a document)_ **and** _A view requests from the model the information that it needs to generate an output representation to the user_ from [wiki : Component interactions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis and where did it say that controller takes data from model and sends it to the view?

Comment: @tereško I said _makes it available to the view_. How that is implemented depends on the framework.

Comment: Your code is what implements MVC, not the favorite-framework-of-day.

Answer (score 5):

> <sub>There are two approaches for handling this and both actually would indicate that controller in this case a significant role to play.</sub>

#### The fabled ways of ancients ..

The first option for resolving this issue would be adhering to *classical MVC* as close as possible. This kinda relates to what people mean, when they say *'you cannot do classical MVC for web'*. In *classical MVC* the view observes model layer. And that part can actually be implemented.

If that's the approach you want to take, then you will have to learn about Observer <sup>[(1)](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ObserverPattern), [(2)](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer)</sup> pattern and how to use it in PHP <sup>[(1)](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splobserver.php), [(2)](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-the-observer-pattern/)</sup>. Though there has been [some](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DeprecatingTheObserverPattern) push for moving away from Observer pattern.

Since I have not explored this approach in any meaningful way, I will not give any examples.

#### The puny trail from this decade ..

If you read Fowler's  ["GUI Architectures"](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html) article, you might notice the part which state that views and controllers form pairs. When applying the ideas of MVC to context of web, there are ways to benefit from it in the bootstrapping stage of application.

> <sub>**FYI :** I'm not anymore so sure, that you can call this way "Model2 MVC". There are some significant inconsistencies. I'm gonna poke more at this nagging suspicion some more, when I'm bored.</sub>

Consider this fragment:

```
 $router->route( $request );
 $resource = $request->getParameter('controller');

 $view = new {'Views\\'.$resource}($serviceFactory);
 $controller = new {'Controller\\'$resource}($serviceFactory, $view);

 $method = $request->getMethod(); //post, get & etc.
 $command = $request->getParameter('action');

 $controller->{$command.$method}($request);

 $view->{$command}();
 echo $view->render();
```

The *controller* fragment in your example URL would be `"product"` and *action* would contain `"list"`. I left those names instead of resource/command pair to make it less confusing.

If you start out with a premise that views and controllers are paired to some extent *(whether the pairing is [cohesive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_%28computer_science%29) or not is debatable)*, then you can express it by using same names. This also lets you move the initialization of view out of controller.

Another aspect which is encapsulated in the fragment above is the fact that, due to the request-response nature of web, every operation in controller will require an accompanying one in the view. And similarly to how you have actions in controllers, you can also opt to call specific, route-related methods in the view. That would remove some boilerplate conditionals from views and let you better organize the whole thing *(this is kinda the "highly subjective bit")*.

So .. how do you turn `/product/view/428` request in something visible on site?

As you probably know, the responsibility of controller is to alter the state of model layer, which in this case might code something like this:

```
public function getView( $request )
{
    $warehouse = $this->serviceFactory->provide('warehouse');
    $warehouse->chooseItem( $request->getParameter('id') );
}
```

The your view instance uses the primed service from model layer to acquire data:

```
public function view()
{
    $warehouse = $this->serviceFactory->provide('warehouse');
    ..
    ..
    // retrieve data about sales for product with ID: 428
    $something = $warehouse->getSalesFigures();
    ..
}
```

The exact implementation of view will depend on how far off deepend you are willing to go. Two most reasonable options would be:

- fetch data, inspect it and if necessary choose templates and dump data into them
- use a set of [presentation objects](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PresentationModel.html) to work with model layer and based on the result bind those presentation objects to ant number of templates

<kbd>my 2 cents</kbd>

Comment: Does the controller pass request params to service and forces service to fetch data from (lets say) database and store this data in the service layer and then view fetches this data from service layer (object) OR controller just passes request param and stores it in the service layer and does not fetch data from DB; then view runs service method which fetches data from DB? I.e. actual data fetching from DB happens in $warehouse->chooseItem() OR in $warehouse->getSalesFigures() ? Thanks

Comment: I think, it's a matter of preference, but I tend to prefer to fetch the data in methods, that are used by controller and view-used methods for packaging of the data.

Comment: @Andrew well ... here is a counter-example. A concept of *"items per page"* is presentational. If your site has two different interfaces( a REST API and a normal site), where in normal site you show 20 items per page and in REST's JSON you list only 10 items. Then the amount of items, that you request from the model layer, would seem to better determined by view's call. Neither of ways is "the best", because each serves a bit different use-case.

Comment: my question was about general data retrieval, but if the data you fetch is for presentational purposes, then logically it should be specifically retrieved in the View. True. On the other hand, do you have similar example when fetching data in controller level would be much more appropriate?

Comment: A simple example: loading a document. Controller tells some kind of `Library` service prepare (fetch) a document and it's associated data for presentation. The view checks if retrieval was successful and either decides to use template for "document not found" page or the assembles the templates for presenting the document. In this case, the view only collects data, that was already retrieved by controller ... at least that's how I would do it. Of course, you should keep in mind, that this is a simplified example with nod description of how presentation objects are utilized in this situation.

Comment: yes, this is the 'standard' data fetching and presenting. But I just had a thought: if you need such basic 'GET' of data (not modify it), what if you would pass request(params) directly to the View and the View would use Service to fetch this data from DB. No need to use Controller. For data Update/Insert you would use controller and for data Select (Get) you would use View only... but I need to think more of possible dangers this way would introduce..

Comment: You have to keep in mind , that in PHP at the time, when you initialize your controller and later - execute a method on it, you have no idea whether you will actually need to do something in that method. Having empty controller methods is more common then you initially would suspect.

Answer (score 0):

In MVC, A controller "controls" the flow of information between the model, where the information is "stored," and the view, where it is displayed.  Therefore, the controller handles all the changes of information and interaction with the models and then sends the necessary information to a view that then displays whatever information was requested/changed/etc.

Comment: -1: controller is not managing flow of information between model and views. Controller is **NOT** aware that information is stored or that view displays anything.

Answer (score 0):

MVC is all about the separation of responsibilities.

- Models are responsible for storing and modeling the application's data.
- Views are responsible for displaying information to the user.
- Controllers actually have multiple responsibilities:

  - Deciding when to Create new instances of a Model.
  - Deciding which instances of Models to Read and passing them to the appropriate View.
  - Deciding which data in a Model instance needs to be Updated based on data passed back from a View.
  - Deciding when to Delete no longer needed instances of a Model.

In other words, Controllers sit between the Models and Views and do all the [business logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_logic) for an application, including figuring out which [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) operations need to happen... although the actual CRUD operations are usually part of the Model itself.

A better name for MVC would probably be MCV to stress how the Controller sits between the Model and View.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. All my business logic is done in my entities. My controllers are very very slim almost nothing in them except extract request data and calling a method in the service layer like register($firstName, $lastName...), updateAccount($firstName, $lastName) etc. My controllers don't even know a database exists along with my entities. They just see a nice clear API from my Services. Use cases really.

Comment: @David Controllers really don't need to know about the database, but they're usually involved in processing user input from views and deciding what to do with it.

Comment: Controllers mostly need to delegate the work to the model layer. It should not do much *business logic* itself.

Comment: @David I think you're almost there. Except that the entities shouldn't take care of any logic at all. You can create services for that. An entity is basically just a data structure.

Comment: -1: you should not recommend "better names" if you do not know what you are talking about. There are no "models". Model is a layer that **contains** all of domain business logic. And controllers have only one responsibility - altering state of model layer and current view.